# Cozy Installation on Ubuntu 14.04: Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am new to Cozy Cloud, and trying to setup on Ubuntu 14.04, as mentioned [Install Cozy on Ubuntu](https://cozy.io/en/host/install/install-on-ubuntu.html):

and while installing the cozy I tried to run the command:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

I am getting the following error:

> W: Failed to fetch
>   https://ubuntu.cozycloud.cc/debian/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages
>   Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT W: Failed to fetch
>   https://ubuntu.cozycloud.cc/debian/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages
>   Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT E: Some index files
>   failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Though the above urls are accessible in browser and downloads package file in a browser, but in the terminal with above command, I am getting an error.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution, my `apt` was configured to use a proxy server. I tried to run `apt-config dump | grep -i proxy` on command line and found an entry for proxy in the following file:

> /etc/apt/apt.conf

Removed the entry and now it's working fine.